# WSWS3770W: Warning: WSDL2Java does not support http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy ,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/ binding namespace

Tags: wsdl, websphere, ibm-rad

My issue began when I generated a web service client (in RAD 9.0.0) from a supplied WSDL.  It ran as it was supposed to, but an UnsupportedNamespaceException was generated each time it ran.  The namespace it objected to is ***won't let me post*** and after searching online I found a replacement in ***won't let me post***.  After modifying the WSDL, the UnsupportedNamespaceException was no longer generated; however, every time I publish the application I get "WSWS3770W: Warning: WSDL2Java does not support http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy ,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/ binding namespace." and a completely new package is generated whose classes contain a multitude of errors.  While I was able to find a replacement (above) for the first namespace mentioned, I've been unable to find a replacement for the second one.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to post the WSDL?

Comment: It looks like you are generating a jax-rpc client.  Wondering if a jax-ws client might work.

Comment: @dbreaux - I don't see any way to post the WSDL.  Maybe I'm not "experienced" enough.

Comment: @Bruce T. - Every other web service in my WebSphere projects does use JAX-RPC, but I actually used JAX-WS for this one, as using JAX-RPC produced two separate packages with unusual classes.

Comment: I wish I knew how to explain this, but when I started working on this today (Monday), all of the "bad behavior" just stopped.  (No more unexpected new package and no more UnsupportedNamespaceException.)  Thanks!